# vuejs append different input on change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have select option where i select type of inputs, and i want to show different type of inputs based on selected option.

#### Example

1. select `input` -> show input fields
2. select `textarea` -> show text areas
3. select `bolean` -> show radio buttons

## Code

Here is where i select my input types,

Notice: `@change="inputType"`

```
<div v-for="(index, a) in variationParents" :key="a">
<el-input placeholder="Please input your variation name" v-model="index.name" class="input-with-select">
    <el-select @change="inputType" v-model="index.type" slot="prepend" placeholder="Select">
        <el-option label="Text" value="input"></el-option>
        <el-option label="Text Area" value="textarea"></el-option>
        <el-option label="Boolean" value="boolean"></el-option>
    </el-select>
</el-input>
</div>
```

`Script`

> Note: I am aware that i am using jQuery instead of vueJs in this
>   function but it was only to test and make sure that i'm getting the
>   right value out of my select options.

```
methods: {
  inputType: function(value) {
    $('.show').html('')
    if(value == 'input') {
      $('.show').html(value)
    } else if(value == 'textarea') {
      $('.show').html(value)
    } else if(value == 'boolean') {
      $('.show').html(value)
    }
  },
}
```

`HTML`

This is where different type of inputs has to be returned, currently it has static input field only, somehow it should be related to function if statements and print related type of inputs

```
<div class="show"></div>  // this DIV was only to test my function values
<el-col :span="9" style="margin-top:15px;display:none;">
    <div v-for="(indexx, b) in variationChilds" :key="b">
        <!-- child's -->
        <el-input v-model="indexx.name" placeholder="Please input your variation value" class="input-with-select">
            <el-button slot="append"  @click="addChild(b)"  type="success" icon="el-icon-plus"></el-button>
            <el-button slot="append" @click="removeChild(b)" v-show="b || ( !b == variationChilds.lenghth > 1)" type="danger" icon="el-icon-delete"></el-button>
        </el-input>
    </div>
</el-col>
```

ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I made 3 different div's, like `<div v-if="selecteVariation == 'input'">` with different values and in each one i Placed separate input types.

## code

```
data(){
  return {
     selecteVariation: '',
  }
},
methods: {
  inputType: function(value) {
     this.selecteVariation = value
  }
}
```

[image: one]

Hope it can help others.

Answer (score 1):

In your div tag. put already the input you have to set and attached a condition on it, see code below

```
<div class="show">
   <input type="text" v-if="index.type == 'input'">
   <textarea v-if="index.type == 'textarea'">
   <input type="radio" v-if="index.type == 'boolean'">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but it couldn't read the `index.type` and stopped view to be render so i made 3 different div's like `<div v-if="selecteVariation == 'input'">` with different values and in each one i Placed separate input types.

Comment: why you can't read the index.type ? did you declare it in the data ?

Comment: no as they are all under same loop `<div v-for="(index, a) in variationParents" :key="a">` it didn't need to be declare i guess.

Comment: Hi, would you mind check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870746/vuejs-return-data-to-nested-variable  i'm sure you're able to help with it, you already did it it's just need to get 1 more value :) appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the value in `inputType`, you can use directly `this.index.type`.

```
methods: {
  inputType: function() {
    const value = this.index.type;
    $('.show').html('')
    if(value == 'input') {
      $('.show').html(value)
    } else if(value == 'textarea') {
      $('.show').html(value)
    } else if(value == 'boolean') {
      $('.show').html(value)
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: thanks but that's not my issue, my issue is input types (html fields)

Answer (score 0):

you have the v-model already in the select options, why did you need @click function handler while you may do that thing like this and also can free your code from jquery..

```
<el-input placeholder="Please input your variation name" v-model="index.name" class="input-with-select">
    <el-select v-model="index.type" slot="prepend" placeholder="Select">
        <el-option label="Text" value="input"></el-option>
        <el-option label="Text Area" value="textarea"></el-option>
        <el-option label="Boolean" value="boolean"></el-option>
    </el-select>
</el-input>
<div>
   <input type="text" v-if="index.type == 'input'">
   <textarea v-if="index.type == 'textarea'">
   <input type="radio" v-if="index.type == 'boolean'">
</div>
```

and set in

```
data() {
  return{
    index.type = ''
  }
}
```

so initially the input will not showing any type of input.