# vuejs return data to nested variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have nested form which works fine, but since i've added upload file to it, it can't get image name.

## Logic

1. I add option with type (e.g. `type = checkbox, name = test`)
2. Then I add multiple options for it (e.g. `name = option1, photo =
   abc.jpg` and `name = option2, photo = def.png`)

**Now, without photo part all is good.** but when i added photo part to children it has 2 issues:

1. Photo name can't be return in that array
2. Photo for all options will be set to latest selected image
   (screenshot below)

#### Screenshot

[image: one]

## Code

`HTML`

```
<el-form-item label="Option Name">
    <el-col :span="10" style="margin-top:15px;">
        <!-- parent -->
        <div v-for="(index, a) in optionParents" :key="a">
        <el-input placeholder="Please input your variation name" v-model="index.name" class="input-with-select">
            <el-select @change="optionType" v-model="index.type" slot="prepend" placeholder="Select">
                <el-option label="Drop-down" value="dropdown"></el-option>
                <el-option label="Checkbox" value="checkbox"></el-option>
                <el-option label="Radio Button" value="radio"></el-option>
            </el-select>
        </el-input>
        </div>

    </el-col>

    <!-- Children -->
    <el-col class="line text-center" :span="3">Option Value(s)</el-col>
    <el-col :span="11" style="margin-top:15px;">

        <div v-if="selecteOption == 'dropdown'">
            <div v-for="(indexx, b) in optionChilds" :key="b">
                <!-- child's -->
                <el-input v-model="indexx.name" placeholder="Please input your option value" class="input-with-select">
                    <el-button slot="append"  @click="addOptionChild(b)"  type="success" icon="el-icon-plus"></el-button>
                    <el-button slot="append" @click="removeOptionChild(b)" v-show="b || ( !b == optionChilds.lenghth > 1)" type="danger" icon="el-icon-delete"></el-button>
                </el-input>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div v-if="selecteOption == 'checkbox'">
            <div v-for="(indexx, b) in optionChilds" :key="b">
                <el-input v-model="indexx.name" :rows="3" placeholder="Please input your option value" class="input-with-select">
                </el-input>
                <!-- upload image -->
                <el-upload
                    class="upload-demo"
                    action="/api/upload/single"
                    :on-change="handleChange"
                    v-model="indexx.photo"  // as you can see my v-model here is same as my input just is set to photo value
                    :limit="1"
                    :multiple="false"
                    :file-list="fileList"
                    :on-exceed="handleExceed"
                    :on-remove="handleRemove"
                    :on-preview="handlePictureCardPreview"
                    :on-success="handleOptionSuccess"
                    :before-remove="beforeRemove"
                    :auto-upload="true">
                    <el-button size="small" type="primary">Click to upload</el-button>
                    <div slot="tip" class="el-upload__tip">jpg/png files with a size less than 500kb</div>
                </el-upload>
                <!-- upload image -->
                <el-button-group>
                    <el-button size="small" @click="addOptionChild(b)"  type="success" icon="el-icon-plus"></el-button>
                    <el-button size="small" @click="removeOptionChild(b)" v-show="b || ( !b == optionChilds.lenghth > 1)" type="danger" icon="el-icon-delete"></el-button>
                </el-button-group>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div v-if="selecteOption == 'radio'">
            <div v-for="(indexx, b) in optionChilds" :key="b">
                <!-- child's -->
                <el-input v-model="indexx.name" :rows="3" placeholder="Please input your option value" class="input-with-select">
                </el-input>
                <!-- upload image -->
                <el-upload
                    class="upload-demo"
                    action="/api/upload/single"
                    :on-change="handleChange"
                    v-model="indexx.photo" // as you can see my v-model here is same as my input just is set to photo value
                    :limit="1"
                    :multiple="false"
                    :file-list="fileList"
                    :on-exceed="handleExceed"
                    :on-remove="handleRemove"
                    :on-preview="handlePictureCardPreview"
                    :on-success="handleOptionSuccess"
                    :before-remove="beforeRemove"
                    :auto-upload="true">
                    <el-button size="small" type="primary">Click to upload</el-button>
                    <div slot="tip" class="el-upload__tip">jpg/png files with a size less than 500kb</div>
                </el-upload>
                <!-- upload image -->
                <el-button-group>
                    <el-button size="small" @click="addOptionChild(b)"  type="success" icon="el-icon-plus"></el-button>
                    <el-button size="small" @click="removeOptionChild(b)" v-show="b || ( !b == optionChilds.lenghth > 1)" type="danger" icon="el-icon-delete"></el-button>
                </el-button-group>
            </div>
        </div>

    </el-col>
    <el-col :span="24" style="margin-top:15px;">
        <el-button type="primary" @click="addOptions" native-type="submit">Save Options</el-button>
    </el-col>
</el-form-item>
```

`Script`

> Note: I have removed everything else that wasn't related to this
>   options, all you see in code below is related to options
>   functionality.

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            fileList: [],
            selecteOption: '',
            savedOptions: [],
            optionParents: [
                {
                    name: '',
                    type: ''
                }
            ],
            optionChilds: [
                {
                    name: '',
                    photo: '',
                }
            ],
            form: {
                name: '',
                slug: '',
                price: '',
                new_price: '',
                sku: '',
                qty: 1,
                active: '',
                photo: '',
                shortDesc: '',
                longDesc: '',
                tags: [],
                brand_id: '',
                categories: [],
                user_id: '',
                seoTitle: '',
                seoTags: '',
                seoPhoto: '',
                seoDescription: '',
                variations: [],
                options: [],
                condition: '',
                isbn: '',
                ean: '',
                upc: '',
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addOptionChild(index){
            this.optionChilds.push({name: '', photo: ''});
        },
        removeOptionChild(index){
            this.optionChilds.splice(index, 1);
        },
        optionType: function(value) {
            this.selecteOption = value
        },
        addOptions(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            axios.post('/api/admin/options/store', {
                childs: this.optionChilds,
                parent: this.optionParents,
            })
            .then(res => {
                this.optionChilds = [
                    {
                        name: '',
                        photo: ''
                    }
                ],
                this.optionParents = [
                    {
                        name: '',
                        type: ''
                    }
                ],
                this.savedOptions.push(res.data.data);
                this.form.options.push(res.data.data.id);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                var errors = error.response.data;
                    let errorsHtml = '<ol>';
                    $.each(errors.errors,function (k,v) {
                            errorsHtml += '<li>'+ v + '</li>';
                    });
                    errorsHtml += '</ol>';

                this.$notify.error({
                    title: 'Error',
                    dangerouslyUseHTMLString: true,
                    message: errorsHtml
                });
            })
        },
        handleOptionSuccess(res, file) {
            this.optionChilds.photo = res.data;  // this s supposed to set uploaded image name in options `photo: ''`
        },
        handleChange(file, fileList) {
            this.fileList = fileList.slice(-3);
        },
        handlePictureCardPreview(file) {
            this.dialogImageUrl = file.url;
            this.dialogVisible = true;
        },
        handleExceed(files, fileList) {
            this.$message.warning(`The limit is 1, you selected ${files.length} files this time, add up to ${files.length + fileList.length} totally, remove old image and try again.`);
        },
        beforeRemove(file) {
            return this.$confirm(`Cancel the transfert of ${ file.name } ?`);
        },
    },

}
```

#### Sending data

This is what is sending to back-end when i hit save button

[image: two]

## Question

1. How can I update `photo: ''` data with uploaded image?
2. How to fix images of getting same file for all options?

Comment: what do you mean of same file of all options ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 if you see my first screenshot, both my options have file named `Asset1-100.jpg`(marked with arrow) when i select an image it will be set for both options!

Comment: @Qonvex620 any idea?

Comment: I think you cant bind model into your file uploaded. You must attach an event to it and inside of it, get the selected file then initialize that file to your photo

Comment: @Qonvex620 I have event for that `handleOptionSuccess(res, file) {` this event is firing when selected file has uploaded successfully and returning `res.data` which is value that i need to set in my `photo: ""`

Comment: then this code will not work this.optionChilds.photo = res.data; , since your optionChilds is an array right ?

Comment: Ok i've fixed repeating image issue, it was `:file-list="fileList"` after removing it now each option get separate image, yet not able to set `res.data` in `photo`

Comment: @Qonvex620 exactly you're right

Comment: you have to pass also the current index of your photo model to change the exact photo you have to change

Comment: ...........how?

Comment: but your res.data is correct ? because you have to convert also your image to base64 right ? to upload it through axios

Comment: it is correct it's name of *uploaded file* file already has been uploaded. this is the final value that i want to store in my column

Comment: yes but that file should be converted to base64 before you send it to server

Comment: @Qonvex620 as i said file is already uploaded and stored in my host, this is returned name of stored file. `:auto-upload="true"` i am uploading file on select now all i need is to set name of it in photo:""

Comment: see here https://ibb.co/C0KYBTK i have selected file `7.jpg` it is uploaded already and name is in console. now i just want to set that name in console to `photo: ""`

Comment: Ah okay, but your problem is now is how you can access the index of that photo in array right ?

Comment: ............yes

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

About my first issue :

I've fixed repeating image issue, by removing `:file-list="fileList"` after that it each option get separate image

About second issue: (Thanks to Qonvex620 ideas)

I have changed my `on-change` method to

```
:on-change="handleChange(b)"
```

Then added this to my data:

```
return {
  index: '',
}
```

And finally my functions to:

```
handleOptionSuccess(res, file) {
  this.optionChilds[this.index].photo = res.data;
},
handleChange(file, fileList) {
  this.index = file;
},
```

Now each option of mine gets their stored image name.

Hope it help others as well

Answer (score 1):

I think not the good way but will solve your problem as of now.

In your data put new variable like

```
data() {
  return {
     selected_index: ''
  }

}
```

now in your button uploaded, set the value of it that match the current index like this

```
<el-button size="small" type="primary" @click="selected_index = b">Click to upload</el-button>
```

so now in your handler you could access it's index like this

```
handleOptionSuccess(res, file) {
    this.optionChilds[this.selected_index].photo = res.data;  // this s supposed to set uploaded image name in options `photo: ''`
},
```

here how you access it inline with your index. Change handleOptionSuccess to this

```
:on-success="handleOptionSuccess($event, b)"
```

now in your function handleOptionSuccess you could do it like

```
handleOptionSuccess(res, index) {
    this.optionChilds[index].photo = res.data;  // this s supposed to set uploaded image name in options `photo: ''`
},
```

Comment: there is no other way? because if i change my save button `@click` to your solution then i will lose ability of saving my options :/

Comment: I mean at the moment you select file put this "selected_index = b", I'm not sure if its in your file input maybe

Comment: maybe in your <el-upload>, when you click that set the selected_index to b, something like that

Comment: we need to send `b` to `handleOptionSuccess` i guess

Comment: Yes I;m thinking also that but I don't know yet how to do that cause it will overwrite the res and file you pass

Comment: in document here is something about `ref` https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload#attributes

Comment: Yes you could do that, I'm just giving you idea how you can do it

Comment: i understand bro, i'm just not sure about the way to passing `b` so i gave you idea about `ref` maybe you could tell me how to send `b` with `ref`, like that

Comment: as soon as i select my types to show inputs it returns this `Property or method "$event" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`  this happens even before i try to upload file

Comment: ok, changing `$event` to `$emit` fixed the error but update part removed photo from my array  :/

Comment: I don't know why it was removed. Maybe you can present a jsfiddle for it

Comment: i think success handler requires second option as `file` we can't change it to `index` because i debug now even after upload i lose ability of getting res

Comment: yep the issue is with res now, i've tried static name it's been set to photo value. since we removed `file` res is lost

Comment: can you put :on-change="this.selected_index = b" in your uploader ? This is your way as of now

Comment: i did it :) similar with your solution a little bit different